# Getting relational table data

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following tables:

```
member
id, firstName, lastName

team
id, name

teamMember
id, teamId, memberId
```

I am trying to access the relational table so I can output the members firstName and Lastname:

```
$sql = "SELECT member.id, member.firstName, member.lastName, team.id, teamMember.id, teamMember.memberId, teamMember.teamId 
        FROM teamMember 
        JOIN member
        JOIN team
        ON teamMember.memberId = member.id
        WHERE dashboardId = 1 AND team.id = 1";
```

I have set a hard value in the team.id so I can test to make sure it returns the members of team 1 for now.

so the end goal here is that I need to access the relational table to give me back the names of members that are associated to the team id set in the select query by ID.

I am struggling to get the output need.

And return the values like so:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "{$row['firstName']} {$row['lastName']}<br>";
    }
}
```

The error I am seeing is:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
```

Which refers to: `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {`

The output I want to see is the members `firstName` and `lastName` from the `member` table

Comment: Please mention what are you getting and what output you are expecting.

Comment: @ParantapParashar I have included some more information.

Comment: have you tried running a var dump on `$result` to see if your query is outputting correctly?

Comment: Yeah, it comes back as bool(false);

Comment: So your query is broken

Comment: Sure is! that what I am struggling with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably want all the results or rows associated to the desired team id. But, Using a INNER JOIN you would only get a single row for one team because that is how JOIN works.

Instead you should use a query like this :

```
SELECT member.id, member.firstName, member.lastName, team.id, teamMember.id, teamMember.memberId, teamMember.teamId 
        FROM teamMember 
        JOIN member
        ON teamMember.memberId = member.id
        WHERE dashboardId = 1 AND teamMember.teamId = 1"
```

Hope  this would work.

However, As of bool(false), your query was also broken and would not get you desired results. 
In your query you have joined three tables and defined the condition for only one. This would be what your query should look like

```
"SELECT member.id, member.firstName, member.lastName, team.id, teamMember.id, teamMember.memberId, teamMember.teamId 
        FROM teamMember 
        JOIN member
        ON teamMember.memberId = member.id
        JOIN team
        ON teamMember.teamId= team.id
        WHERE dashboardId = 1 AND team.id = 1";
```

Comment: That does not seem to have resolved the issue I still back a bool(false) on the $result

Comment: This is because you do not have a `dashboardId` in any of the tables.So you should remove it from the query.

Comment: its still only returning on even though I removed the dashboardId

Comment: It happens if I try to put `echo "{$row['firstName']} {$row['lastName']}<br>";` into a variable and use that variable somewhere else it only bring back a single result